# Jersey error on @DELETE: "Unsupported HTTP method: DELETE"

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, wildfly

I do RESTful application in Jersey (deployed on WildFly 8.1.0.Final) but I have a problem with testing methods @DELETE. All other (GET, POST, PUT) work as expected. However, when calling @DELETE I receive the following error message

```
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Filter: Unsupported HTTP method: DELETE
```

I test RESTful interface via a plugin in Google Chrome: Advanced REST Client. How can I fix it?

Resource class: I deleted other methods for better clarity.

```
@Path(value = "destination")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public class DestinationResource {

public DestinationResource() {}

@DELETE
@Path(value = "/{id}")
public Response deleteDestination(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    //Doing something
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```

}

EDIT: I added CORS.filter but still nopt working. Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
 see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e194 -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <!-- The CORS filter with parameters -->
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <!-- Note: All parameters are options, if omitted the CORS
         Filter will fall back to the respective default values.
      -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>X-Count-records</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>3600</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Show us how the CORS filter is configured. It is causing this error, not your JAX-RS class.

Comment: Maybe there is problem because I didnt configured CORS filter at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, OPTIONS</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Do you see DELETE listed there? I don't.

Comment: I don´t see it too. Stupid mistake that cost me 5 hours of my life. Thanks for help now it is working.